# How can I use foreach to process a multidimensional php array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, foreach

I parsed a JSON file with `json_decode`, and the result is a long multidimensional array like the following:

```
Array
(
[Basic] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [text] => Taunt.
                [playerClass] => Shaman
                [locale] => enUS
                [mechanics] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Taunt
                            )
                    )
            )
    )

[Classic] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [cardId] => CS2_188o
                [name] => 'Inspired'
                [mechanics] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => OneTurnEffect
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

I want to use a `foreach` to insert the data into a datatable but I can't make it work with this multidimensional array.  How would I do that?

Comment: What is your question and what is your problem?

Comment: My problem is that i cant build the foreach code for this multidimensional arrary.

Comment: Yes, all the community allow you to do that. Read docs to know how to do it: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I went through your code and removed a lot of the entries that had a similar structure.  This way, your question is much faster to read, and any solution that works with the remaining data will allow you to read the original data (I also removed several excess blank lines that only spaced things out).  It would really help if you could [edit] in the datatable you want to put this data into.  (For example, how would you process an individual piece of info without using foreach?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
  if (is_array($item)){
    foreach ($item as $it) {
      echo $it["name"];
    }
  }
  echo $item["cardId"];
  echo $item["name"];
  ....
}
```

Comment: This working with a single arrary correct, but here we have a litle big arrary as you can see Arrary -> Arrary -> Array.

Comment: I changed my answer: check if current $item is an array.

Comment: i change it a litle bit to include some arrarys over the second foreach.
Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You must use recursive array to do it like this

```
function build($fullArray)
{
    foreach ($fullArray as $item) {
          if (is_array($item)){
            build($item);
          }
          else{
              echo $item["cardId"];
              echo $item["name"];
              ....
        }
    }
}
```